# Acer Aspire L5100 monitor keeps going blank

Tags: windows, windows-vista

My monitor keeps going blank and \i have to keeep switching it on and off or unconnecting and reconecting. I have sent for a new cable but I fear it may be the monitor. Will any Acer monitor fit ?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily any Acer monitor, but any monitor at all (from *any* manufacturer) that connects via DVI or HDMI.  My research suggests that a VGA monitor won't work, though, and they're the most commonly-available sort, so check before you buy.